# Java: Extract two strings from one string using the first occurrence of a splitter?

Tags: java

I have Strings that look something like this:

```
String a = "URL:www.blahblah.com:/username"
```

I want to be able to extract the first part of the String before the first occurrence of `:` and then the rest of the string after the first occurrence of `:`

So I would end up with:

```
String one = "URL"
String two = "www.blahblah.com:/username"
```

Thanks

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I don't want you to write a class for me. 

I have a String and I want to be able to split it in to two parts on the first occurrence of "sign" in my example ':'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few choices. You could use [`String#split(String, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) with a limit,

```
String a = "URL:www.blahblah.com:/username";
String [] res = a.split(":", 2);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res));
```

Or you could use [`indexOf(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29) and then use [substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) with the relative indexes,

```
int pos = a.indexOf(":");
String b = a.substring(0, pos);
String c = a.substring(pos+1);
System.out.printf("part 1 = %s, part 2 = %s%n", b, c);
```

Here I get (respectively)

```
[URL, www.blahblah.com:/username]
part 1 = URL, part 2 = www.blahblah.com:/username
```

Comment: I would say the first option you provided is a fair bit tidier. 

Is there any advantage to doing it like the second option you provide? 


Thanks

Comment: @Mo. Don't worry about micro-optimizations like that. Pick the one you prefer.

Comment: One last question.

Why do you have the two backslashes before the ":"? Its to ensure the value after it is used as a actual string rather than a regex reserved sign?

Comment: @Mo. Yes. colon isn't. So it's safe to remove. In fact. I'll edit it. Force of habit.

Comment: You should keep it! Just write a little note on it for someone looking at the answer so they know why they are doing it. It could useful for other people looking at the answer in the future who might be using a reserved operator.

Comment: @Mo. It distracts from the answer. I just upvoted your comment on it, which gives it that *note*. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
String a = "URL:www.blahblah.com:/username";
int index = a.indexOf(":");
String before = a.substring(0,index);
String after = a.substring(index+1);
```

If you use `split`, the second colon matters and you will end up with 3 strings, namely, "URL", "www.blahblah.com", and "/username", which is not what you want as far as I can tell. However, take note that the overloaded method `split(String, int)` will help you control the number of times the splitter pattern is applied, so you can still do this using `split` like so:

```
a.split(":",2);
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/BWCW14488)

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] parts = a.split(":", 1);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String, int)

Comment: `a.split(":", 2);`, not `a.split(":", 1);`

Answer (score 1):

There is method in the String class called "split".
For your above String a you can use:

```
a.split(':', 2);
```

It return an array of string.
Here first parameter is reg-ex and second parameter is number of strings you want.